# Get user rank in a score table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and this could be my user table:

```
id|score
1|10
2|13
3|15
4|7
5|11
```

An user can sees a page with two ranks: rank A and rank B.

RANK A

The first 10 users by score, two possible scenarios: the user who sees this rank is in the first 10 users or not.

User in the first 10: **get list of 10 users**

User not in the first 10: **get list of 11 users (the first 10 + current user with is position in all users)**

RANK B

The first 10 users by score in a given group of ID (sometimes could be 1 sometimes 10 sometimes 0), the same two scenarios: the user is in the first 10 or not.

User in the first 10: **get list of 10 users**

User not in the first 10: **get list of 11 users (the first 10 + current user with is position in the group of ids)**

Is there any way to do it with Eloquent? Otherwise how can I do it in MySql?

Comment: What's the difference between both ranks ? What's a "no-fixed group of ids" ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard An array of given ID. Sometimes could be 1 sometimes 10 sometimes 0. I edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first rank, you could do this with Eloquent :

```
$users = User::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->limit(10)->get();
$currentUser = Auth::user();
$currentUserId = $currentUser->id;
if (!$users->contains('id', $currentUserId)) {
    $users->push($currentUser);
}
```

Since `$users` will be ordered by score, if the current user doesn't exist in top 10, then he has a worse score than the last of the list, so it makes sense to add it to the end.

For the second rank :

```
$idsFilter = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$users = User::whereIn('id', $idsFilter)->orderBy('score', 'DESC')->limit(count($idsFilter))->get();
$currentUser = Auth::user();
$currentUserId = $currentUser->id;
if (!$users->contains('id', $currentUserId)) {
    $users->push($currentUser);
}
return $users;
```

Since you want a fixed list of IDs to rank, it only makes sense to show the IDs, and to add the current user if he's not part of the top X IDs you asked for.

To get the position of the user in rank A, you could do a method on the `User` model such as :

```
public function getPosition()
{        
    return DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
                    FROM users
                    WHERE score > {$this->score}");
}
```

And add a filter on the ids for the rank B, with the same process.

Comment: In both ranks if user is not in the first 10 I need to add it as you did but I also need to know in wich position it's in all user (rank A) and all given ID (rank B). The limit of rank B in your second line is ever 10 like rank A

Comment: Edited my answer.